# how to align a dialog in bottom of another view in android programming

Tags: android, android-layout, view, dialog

i have a relative layout in main activity and want to show a dialog instead of it , after button click . my problem is , by default android show dialog in above screen 
im trying to use dialog getWindow().getAttributes() but it doesnt solve my problem 
how can i do it ?

Comment: show your code you have so far :)